# How to UPDATE a column with cluster IDs in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-cluster

I have a table with points in it, and I want to cluster them.  I had created a separate table to hold the clusters, but I ended up copying all the data from the original table into the new cluster table.  Instead, I would like to add a cluster id (cid) column to the original table, and update it with the cluster id.  I tried

```
INSERT INTO spatial_data (cid) 
SELECT st_clusterdbscan(geog::geometry, eps := 0.01, minPoints := 5) over() as cid 
FROM spatial_data;
```

but it added a lot of new rows that were empty except for the cluster id.

I suspect I need to use the update command instead, but I don't know how to write the WHERE clause.

What is the correct way to populate the new cluster id column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this.  First, create the column in your table.

```
ALTER TABLE point
ADD COLUMN cid integer;
```

Then update your table based on your query.  When you do your DBScan query.  Make sure you select an id field that can be matched back to the points.

```
SET cid = subquery.cid
FROM (SELECT id, st_clusterdbscan(geom, eps := 0.01, minPoints := 5) over() as cid 
      FROM schema.point) AS subquery
WHERE point.id = subquery.id;
```

Comment: You may want to include the `UPDATE spatial_data ` statement

Comment: Do I need to add an id field, or is it safe to match each individual field like so, WHERE point.f1 = subquery.f1 and point.f2 = subquery.f2 and ...

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an id field, that was just an example I used.  Your f1 field is fine if it's unique.